# Node.js - When to do HTML escape to JSON data, server or client side?

Tags: json, client-side, server-side, underscore.js, html-escape

I'm using Node.js and Underscore.js. I can't determine whether to escape JSON data on server side or client side. For underscore doesn't auto escape interpolated values with syntax `<%= someValue %>` but with `<%- someValue %>`, which is in the contrast to EJS and may causes confusion. There was a [issue](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/129) on GitHub and also a [commit](https://github.com/dvv/underscore/commit/a4f4d30440f52c7cef26e8574e8eae384a66db9f) of auto-escape version. But a comment beneath the issue said:

> I'm of the general philosophy that escaping should be done closer to
>   your data than in the templating language

So, any suggestion that when to do HTML escape to AJAX data is better? Here's the server side helper function I have been using:

```
var htmlEscape = function(html){
    return String(html)
    .replace(/&(?!\w+;)/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
};
var xss = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj[i] = xss(obj[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for(var key in obj) {
            // key != '_id' for mongoose doc
            if(obj[key] instanceof Object && !(obj[key] instanceof String) 
                && !(obj[key] instanceof Function) && key != '_id') {
                obj[key] = xss(obj[key]);
            } else if (obj[key] instanceof String || typeof(obj[key]) == "string") {
                obj[key] = htmlEscape(obj[key]);
            } else {
                obj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Then call it whenever return a JSON:

```
res.json(xss(someData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to perform sanitization/escape operations on the server since anyone can mess with your client side code and send the data any way they want.

There is a great node.js module, [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator),  which has an xss() function as well as a bunch other functions to validate/sanitize your data.

Comment: Just noting that the xss sanitizer was deprecated in Version 3 of the node-validator [link](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js)

**Deprecations**

Version 3 of the library deprecated some functionality

**XSS sanitizer: Here's why. Use Google Caja instead.**

Just adding this comment for future reference, agree fully with the answer